# Unable to access javascript function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have functions in javascripts as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        if ($("#ProductName").val().toString() == "") {
            $("#pricingSectionDisplay").hide;
            $("#pricingSectionProductName").val("");
        }
        else {
            $("#pricingSectionDisplay").show;
            $("#pricingSectionProductName").val($("#ProductName").val());
        }


        if ($("#PackSize").val().toString() == "") {
            $("#pricingSectionDisplay").hide;
            $("#pricingSectionPackSize").val("");
        }
        else {
            $("#pricingSectionDisplay").show;
            $("#pricingSectionPackSize").val($("#PackSize").val());
        }
    });

 function pricingSectionDisplay() {
        if ($("#ProductName").val().toString() == "") {
            $("#pricingSectionDisplay").hide;
            $("#pricingSectionProductName").val("");
        }
        else {
            $("#pricingSectionProductName").val($("#ProductName").val());
        }

        if ($("#PackSize").val().toString() == "") {
            $("#pricingSectionDisplay").hide;
            $("#pricingSectionPackSize").val("");
        }
        else {
            $("#pricingSectionPackSize").val($(PackSize).val());
        }
    }
```

Actually I need to fill in labels , having id `pricingSectionProductName` and `pricingSectionPackSize` when textboxes

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProductName, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ProductName", onblur = "pricingSectionDisplay()" })
```

and

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PackSize, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "PackSize", onblur = "pricingSectionDisplay()" })
```

are filled.

My codes does not seem to achieve this.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your method calls like this:

```
$("#pricingSectionDisplay").hide;
```

should be:

```
 $("#pricingSectionDisplay").hide();
```

---

Also, `.val()` already returns a string so there's no reason to call `.toString()` on it.

---

If you need further help, please post the actual relevant HTML (what the browser sees with view/source, not a template).

Answer (score 0):

The id of your helper should be `id='...'`. You don't need to add an `@` because `id` is not a reserved keyword. so write

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProductName, 
     new { @class = "form-control", id = "ProductName", 
      onblur = "pricingSectionDisplay()" })
```

instead of

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProductName, 
              new { @id = "ProductName", 
                    onblur = "pricingSectionDisplay()" })
```

In addition You must call show method like this `show()` and not `show`
The same with hide, write `hide()` instead of `hide`